# Is it possible to export from Fossil SCM into some other DVCS?

Tags: version-control, migration, dvcs, fossil

For many years I used Darcs as my only DVCS...some time ago I explored Monotone which I like as well.

However, the main problem with both is the lack of complete hosting solutions.

[Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) looks as interesting option (although we don't like its use of non-standard wiki markup) considering it's very light in regard to hosting requirements and incorporates distributed bug tracker which eliminates the need for some public hosting solution as in the scenario with darcs & monotone.

However, Fossil is not very widely adopted and still very young project, so I'm curious how does it operate with other, more established DVCS-es (bzr,git,hg)...

Based on the info I've gathered from docs, I see it can only import from CVS although it seems there is some tool which can do import from git.

However, the more serious problem is that, afaict, there is no tool to migrate from Fossil into something else by using e.g. 'standard' fast-export/import toolchain.

In the archive I saw that Dr Hipp mentioned 'deconstruct' command, but not being familiar-enough with Fossil, I'm curious how it can be used for exporting Fossil's artifacts into some other DVCS or if I'm not aware of some other tool/converter for such task?

This is serious issue and the question is if there is no such tool, whether it's better to just use bzr/hg (we are not fan of Git and want that tool operates nicely on Linux/Mac/Win for an open-source project) instead along with their public hostings like LP & Bitbucket?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interestingly enough, but recently (after I've asked this question), Fossil got *import* & *export* commands, so that now it's possible to use Git's *fast-import/export* protocol. (See [Import And Export"](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/inout.wiki).) :-)

No need to tell, but it makes Fossil perfect tool for my DVCS needs and the above dilemma is resolved to my upmost satisfaction. ;)

Comment: that's fine for Git, but what about bazaar or mercurial? Makes me wonder if there might be a general anything-to-git app out there.

Comment: Both bazaar and mercurial have plugins to handle fast-import-export streams. See http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/BzrFastImport & http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FastImportExtension

Comment: Sadly, I find the instructions at that link fail on the fossil repository I am attempting to convert.  It may only handle simpler repos.  My case is the fossil repository behind an Iguana EMR service.