# How to migrate from fossil to hg

Tags: mercurial, migration, fossil

I have a fossil repository.  How can I migrate the commits to a hg repository.  I don't care about issues, wiki, branches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See a previous answer on this issue

- [Is it possible to export from Fossil SCM into some other DVCS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119444/is-it-possible-to-export-from-fossil-scm-into-some-other-dvcs)

And the following extension should help you in exporting fossil repo to another Mercurial.

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FastImportExtension

Fossil to Git uses the same export/import facility

- http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/inout.wiki