# Exporting from fossil to git

Tags: git, fossil

I've been trying to export my fossil repo into git using the [instructions found here](https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/tip/www/inout.wiki). I've seen [this question  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119444/is-it-possible-to-export-from-fossil-scm-into-some-other-dvcs) but it doesn't have an answer to my question.

I followed all the directions on https://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/tip/www/inout.wiki but I can't seem to get it to work.

I did the following:

```
git init new-repo
cd new-repo
fossil export --git ../repo.fossil | git fast-import
```

I get the statistics:

```
git-fast-import statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Alloc'd objects:      10000
Total objects:         8831 (         8 duplicates                  )
      blobs  :         5578 (         0 duplicates       3374 deltas of       5224 attempts)
      trees  :         2509 (         8 duplicates       1419 deltas of       2378 attempts)
      commits:          744 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
      tags   :            0 (         0 duplicates          0 deltas of          0 attempts)
Total branches:           1 (         1 loads     )
      marks:        1048576 (      6322 unique    )
      atoms:           4253
Memory total:          2704 KiB
       pools:          2235 KiB
     objects:           468 KiB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
pack_report: getpagesize()            =       4096
pack_report: core.packedGitWindowSize = 1073741824
pack_report: core.packedGitLimit      = 8589934592
pack_report: pack_used_ctr            =       2936
pack_report: pack_mmap_calls          =        744
pack_report: pack_open_windows        =          1 /          1
pack_report: pack_mapped              =  207355128 /  207355128
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't see anything wrong, but I don't have a working repo. Am I missing a step? I didn't find any more info in the fossil documentation. Thanks in advance.

Edit: As an answer to the question below, I tried it with the -R and without the -R for the export command.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to check out the *trunk* branch of the new Git repository.  By default, the `git init` command creates and checks out an empty branch called *master*.  But Fossil uses *trunk* as its main branch.

So invoke `git checkout trunk` after the `git fast-import` and you'll be able to see all the files in the working directory.

Answer (score 3):

First off, if it did work successfully, it will get imported into `trunk` branch, while git default branch is `master` so try the `git checkout trunk` as @Colin D Bennett said or `git branch` and see if it lists any branches in the repo.

If it didn't work or if `git branch` doesn't list any branches then the `fossil export` didn't work.

Now, I had the same problem before with exporting a fossil repo but with a different error:

[Unable to open database file” when trying to export a fossil repo to git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29158099/4624943)

The way I solved it is:

1. `git init git-repo`
2. `cd fossil-repo`
3. `fossil export --git > git.txt`
4. Move `git.txt` to `git-repo`
5. `type/cat git.txt | git fast-import`
6. `git checkout trunk`
7. Voilà

Comment: I will try and let you know. I gave up on it.

Comment: This worked wonderfully for me, +1

Answer (score 2):

Usage: fossil export --git ?OPTIONS? ?REPOSITORY?

Write an export of all check-ins to standard output.  The export is
written in the git-fast-export file format assuming the --git option is
provided.  The git-fast-export format is currently the only VCS 
interchange format supported, though other formats may be added in
the future.

Run this command within a checkout.  **Or use the -R** or --repository
option to specify a Fossil repository to be exported.

**Only check-ins are exported** using --git.  Git does not support tickets 
or wiki or events or attachments, so none of those are exported.

If the "--import-marks FILE" option is used, it contains a list of
rids to skip.

If the "--export-marks FILE" option is used, the rid of all commits and
blobs written on exit for use with "--import-marks" on the next run.

Options:
  --export-marks FILE          export rids of exported data to FILE
  --import-marks FILE          read rids of data to ignore from FILE
  --repository|-R REPOSITORY   export the given REPOSITORY

Comment: I did it both ways. with and without.

Comment: Try to create simple repo and convert it, I think that it can convert only simple repos...

Comment: Ah. I suppose I can do that. But I guess that wouldn't help me with the repo I am trying to export. Are there any work-arounds for larger repos?

Comment: Migrating all your sources to new repo, and try to export this clean repo to git