# "Unable to open database file" when trying to export a fossil repo to git

Tags: git, version-control, fossil

I'm getting a `fossil.exe: [<repo path>]: unable to open database file` when I'm trying to export a `fossil` repo to git on Windows.

Here's the steps I made:

1. git init new-repo
2. cd new-repo
3. fossil.exe export --git "fossil_repo_path" | git fast-import

Comment: Which version of fossil? Did you specify the correct repository path and name, or is new-repo located inside a fossil work directory?

Comment: I'm using version 1.32, but the original fossil repo was created with an older version which I don't know.
Yes I specified the correct path and No, the new-repo is not inside a fossil work directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out what was causing the problem, but I found a workaround:

1. `git init git-repo`
2. `cd fossil-repo`
3. `fossil export --git > git.txt`
4. Move `git.txt` to `git-repo`
5. `type/cat git.txt | git fast-import`
6. `git checkout trunk`
7. Voilà

Comment: `fossil export --git` works fine from inside and outside the `fossil` repo directory, I think the problem is with piping the output to `git fast-import`